# Navbar drop-down menu width problem and hover problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, navbar

I created a navbar having a drop down menu displayed when the button is hovered upon. This is the codepen: https://codepen.io/sahxil/pen/qBoVgXg

I have three problems:

1. The anchor tag with the drop-down menu is taking the width of it's drop-down menu, whereas I want it's width to be normal and there should be no changes in the navigation bar when that anchor tag is hovered upon except for the drop-down menu to appear.
2. The red underline below the anchor tag having a drop-down menu is displaced and is having width equal to 30% of drop-down menu' width(the underline has the width equal to 30% of anchor tag width, but the width of anchor tag somehow becomes equal to drop-down menu' width)
3. I want the drop down to appear only when hovered upon, and to disappear when the cursor is out of the anchor tag. The `mouseover` `EventListener` seems to work but the `mouseout` doesn't. What exact code should I change in my JavaScript to make it work.

How, do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With something simple like a drop-down menu, it's a lot easier (and reliable) to use CSS instead of JavaScript where you can, which is what looks like messed up your menu. I fixed the menu with some CSS [hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) and [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) selectors.

The other two issues involved some incorrect [position attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) as well as some unnecessarily complex CSS attributes, classes, and elements working against each other, as well as some JavaScript e. I refactored a lot of the HTML and classes to be cleaner, and removed your `option` and `simple` classes, as well as some of your unnecessary divs.

To fix the red underline, I used a combination of CSS [variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) and the [calc() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to position it correctly, doing two main things.

First of all, I set a `--width` variable, as well as the actual width of the line itself, to be the same as that of the button (an li), but minus two characters (2[em](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#:%7E:text=Relative%20to-,em,-Font%20size%20of)), so that it would look about the same width as the text within the button.

```css
ul:hover::after {
  --width: calc(100% - 2em);
  width: var(--width);
}
```

And then to center it, I used calc() functions to set the `left` property to half of the available space.

```css
left: calc(calc(100% - var(--width))/2);
```

I also changed your `ul` into a `menu`, and made it `display: flex` with a gap and padding, instead of the different margins that you had.

I linked my fixed (and simplified) code below. Hopefully that all makes sense! Feel free to reach out if you need more help!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #121212;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 999;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#header.headerr__black {
  background-color: #121212;
}

#navbar {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 0;
}

#navbar li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

ul {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

ul:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: -0.2em;
  left: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul:hover li {
  display: block;
}


/* For changing color of navbar buttons when hovered on
and keeping the current page button as red */

#navbar ul a:hover {
  color: #e50914;
}


/* For current page button eg: Why Snap Smile(if active); to have an underline when
that page is active or other buttons to display underline when hovered on */

ul:hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  --width: calc(100% - 2em);
  width: var(--width);
  height: 3px;
  background: #e50914;
  bottom: 0.6em;
  left: calc(calc(100% - var(--width))/2);
}

.logo {
  width: 6em;
}

a.sBtn-text {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
}

a.sBtn-text:hover,
a.sBtn-text.active {
  color: #e50914;
}

menu {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  background: #141414;
  display: none;
}

ul:hover menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}

.select-menu.active .options {
  display: block;
}

.select-menu.inactive .options {
  display: none;
}

.options .option {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  align-items: center;
}

div.select-btn {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section id="header" class="headerr">
  <div id="navbar">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
    </a>
    <ul>
      <a href="what.html">What is Snap Smile</a>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <a href="#">Teeth Spacing</a>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <a href="solutions.html">Solutions</a>
      <menu>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Teeth Spacing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Discolored/Stained Teeth</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Chipped Teeth</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Missing Teeth</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Straighter Smile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Whiter Smile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Cosmetic Enhancement</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Night Guard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Dental Florosis</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Mild Teeth Crowding</a>
        </li>
      </menu>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <a href="how.html">How it Works</a>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <a href="">
        <i class="fa-sould fa-headset fa-2x"></i>
      </a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```